# debug in spring tools suite

Tags: spring, debugging

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching basics".
Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.core.runtime.IExtensionPoint.getLabel()" because the return value of "org.eclipse.core.runtime.IExtensionRegistry.getExtensionPoint(String, String)" is null
```

debug not working ?

almost trying but use

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.